# Сумма двух первых и последних цифр в четырехзначном числе

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу получать сумму двух первых и последних цифр в 4-хзначном числе, но натыкаюсь на ошибку (TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable)

```
list_of_num = []
for i in range(1000, 9999):
    num = i
    b = sum(int(n) for n in num[0:2])
    c = sum(int(n) for n in num[2:4])
    if c == b:
        list_of_num.append(num)
print(list_of_num)
```

Comment: Число нельзя индексировать. А вот строки можно: `num = str(i)`.

Comment: А вообще найти цифру в числе можно комбинируя остаток от деления (`%`) и целочисленное деление (`//`). Это более производительный вариант.

Comment: А если вам нужны только `c == b` такие числа, нельзя ли изначально перебирать  от 10 до 99 и собрать их комбинации? Вместо перебора всех чисел.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно:

```
def list_of_nums():
    list_of_num = []
    for i in range(1000, 9999+1):
        num = i
        b = (num % 10) + (num % 100 // 10) # sum of the last 2 digits
        num //= 100
        c = (num % 10) + (num % 100 // 10) # sum of the first 2 digits
        if b == c:
            list_of_num.append(i)
    return list_of_num
```